# Input value not being retrieved

Tags: php, html, checkbox

PHP variable won't return the POST value of a checkbox; it says the variable is undefined

I then try to insert the POST data into my database, but to no avail.

Tried retrieving with a PHP variable; tried changing the checkbox to a radiobutton (same issue); tried moving the checkbox elsewhere

```
<form method="post">
<label><input type="checkbox" name="farming_type" value="1" >Organic</label><br />
<label><input type="checkbox" name="grazing_type" value="2" />Grass-fed</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="antibiotics" value="3" />Antibiotic-free</label><br />
<label><input type="checkbox" name="hormones" value="4" />Hormone-free</label>

<input type="submit" name="submit" value='Create' style='margin-left:3px;font-weight:bold;color:green;' />
</form>

<?php if (isset($_POST['submit'])) { ?>
<?php $farming_type = $_POST["farming_type"]; ?>
```

Expected: a returned variable.
Actual: undefined variable

Comment: Have you defined `method="POST"` in your form?

Comment: Try dumping your variables to see what's coming across.

Comment: Can you post your full code example? As written, there are a number of syntactical errors with your posted sample (i.e., no <?php ?> markers around your code and no <form> tags in your html). It might help us better assist you.

Comment: The code is too long to all be pasted, but yes, I used <form method="post"> along with PHP markers

Comment: Is there also a 'submit' button in your form to trigger the POST?

Comment: Yes, I will add that to the code above

Comment: Put the submit button **inside** the form.

Comment: Your PHP code should read as follows: <?php if (isset($_POST['submit'])) { 
$farming_type = $_POST["farming_type"]; }?>

Comment: The issue was that the POST was returning nothing because the tickbox wasn't ticked. So I added an if !isset and set it to 0

Answer (score 0):

There should be a button to submit the form, then in the php block, an 'isset' check should be performed

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['submitButton']))
{

     $farming_type = $_POST["farming_type"];

} ?>
```

Comment: Do you have the 'isset' posted in your code as well?

Comment: Yes. The code works for radio buttons, but not for checkboxes

Comment: I think you also need to add an 'action' to your form tag

Comment: <form action="#" method="post">

Comment: I have action="index.php". The code works if I change the buttons to radio buttons

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187877/discussion-between-russ-j-and-user1228907).

Answer (score 0):

> <
>   ?php $farming_type = $_POST["farming_type"]; ?>

***Here $farming_type surely return undefined unless you use isset() function***

Answer (score 0):

A variable won't be defined in PHP if the checkbox isn't checked. You'll have to use isset() to see if the box was checked, and provide a fallback value in your PHP script if it wasn't.

```
$farming_type = (isset($_POST['farming_type'])) ? $_POST['farming_type'] : "Not specified.";
```

http://form.guide/php-form/php-form-checkbox.html